# C++ container with non-copyable non-movable element type

Tags: c++, arrays, containers, noncopyable

I need a container of elements that are neither copyable nor movable. These elements are not default constructible, but their constructors get identical arguments.

The size of the container does not change during it's lifetime. It should be as simple as a built-in array, but it's size is determined at run-time when the constructor is called.

Is there an easy way to implement that without the overhead of memory allocation and indirection incurred by using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`?

Comment: have you tried the emplace functions? I am not sure how well they work with non moveable though.

Comment: You'll need a solution based on one allocation of memory and placement-`new`ing the elements.

Comment: @Hayt `std::vector<T>` does not compile with non-copyable and non-movable `T`. `emplace()`ing elements requires the vector to grow (possibly). Growing operations require, that the elements can be copied or moved.

Comment: `deque` and `list` both only require `T` be `EmplaceConstructible` when using `emplace_back`. Maybe check boost--doesn't it have a container that places limits on the number of elements it can have? `set::emplace` doesn't have a listed requirement for `T` on cppreference...

Comment: @RalphTandetzky ah forgot about that. you're right there.

Comment: I'm sure there is a high-voted question about this but I can't find it now... this is one of the problems with vector, even though the internal structure supports this usage it doesn't have the right constructors and member functions.  Maybe there is a niche open for a vector-like container which allows capacity to be set on construction, and has a non-reallocating emplace/resize (which throws if no capacity is available)

Comment: @RalphTandetzky `std::vector<T>` does compile with non-copyable and non-movable `T` , but only if you don't use functions that require a copy/move.  (which includes all insert functions)

Comment: Do you have the requirement that `&v[0]` can be used to access the storage like a C-style array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple, yet incomplete solution under the assumption that each element is constructed with the same arguments.  It uses [placement `new`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) to construct the elements in-place (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
#include <new>

// sample structure, non-copyable, non-moveable, non-default-constructible
struct Foo
{
  Foo() = delete;
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator = (const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
  Foo& operator = (Foo&&) = delete;

  Foo(int a, char b, double c) : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c) { }

  int m_a;
  char m_b;
  double m_c;
};

template <typename T>
struct MyArray
{
  // Array ctor constructs all elements in-place using the
  // provided parameters
  template <typename... Args>
  MyArray(std::size_t sz, Args&&... args)
    : m_sz(sz),
      m_data(static_cast<T*>(malloc(sz * sizeof(T))))
  {
    for (std::size_t i=0; i<m_sz; ++i)
    {
      new (&m_data[i]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  }

  ~MyArray()
  {
    for (std::size_t i=0; i<m_sz; ++i)
    {
      m_data[i].~T();
    }
    free(m_data);
  }

  std::size_t m_sz;
  T *m_data;
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo(1, '2', 3.0);
  std::size_t s = 5;
  MyArray<Foo> foo_arr(s, 1, '2', 3.0);
}
```

Note that a few things are missing:

- This basic implementation will leak memory if an exception is thrown inside `MyArray`'s constructor.
- You will probably want an iterator implementation, `begin()`/`end()` operators etc., for more convenience and to get the same behaviour as provided by the standard containers.
- For illustration's sake I also didn't bother with proper encapsulation.  You should probably make `m_sz` and `m_data` private members.

Comment: Just to add an FYI to this: the technique is called placement new. And it's the exact same technique I was working on when I hit refresh and saw it was already posted.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, and I'm using a simple workaround.
What's wrong with this example?

```
class test{
  const int a;
public:
  test(int i): a(i) {} //no default constructor
};

//trick for static initializer
template <typename T> class defer_params: public T{
public:
  defer_params(): T(1) {} //fixed params
};

//static array
//test list1[5]; //this doesn't work
defer_params<test> list2[5];
```

Regards,
Gabriel

Answer (score -2):

"Is there an easy way to implement that without the overhead of memory allocation and indirection incurred by using std::vector>?"

The overhead is so minimal, why do you care?  This is almost certainly premature optimisation, and you're just going to make yourself a maintenance headache.