# How to insert values to vector of const pointers

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am aware of the following post:

[Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t)

however I am not able to solve my problem. I am trying to define a vector with a list of const shared_ptr of my class "Example", because these class instances should not be changed.

```
std::vector<const std::shared_ptr<Example>> myVector;
```

But when I try to add a const value to the vector, it does not compile:

```
const std::shared_ptr<Example> example = createMyObject();
myVector.append(example); // compiler error
```

I am also aware of this post:
[Non-copyable elements in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906014/non-copyable-elements-in-vector)
however there is no real answer to my issue. Since my class Example offers several setters, I need to make them const so they cannot be changed.

Comment: `const std::shared_ptr` the const applies to the `std::shared_ptr` not `Example`.  Try `std::vector< std::shared_ptr< const Example >> myVector;`

Comment: `std::vector` does not have a `append` function

Comment: `const std::shared_ptr<Example>` is not `std::shared_ptr<const Example>` (as well as `Example*const` is not `const Example*`). Notice how the location of `const`s is "reverted" between smart pointers and raw pointers...

Comment: In the first question you linked, substitute `T` with `shared_ptr<Example>` and it exactly explains why your code can not work.

Comment: Did you want a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Example>>` maybe? Then just replace the non-existent `append` with `push_back` and everything should work.

Comment: Ok yes sorry about `append`, it is a remainder of the framework I use but wanted to keep out of the question.

I have tried it with `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Example>>` and you are right, the instances cannot be changed, but however I can still change the shared_ptr stored on a index in the vector...

Comment: @malajedala then only make `const std::vector< std::shared_ptr< const Example >> myVector;` available to client code that is not allowed to change the vector. Have a think about your full requirements and perhaps update the post.

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926929) to the question you said you are aware of? It specifically covers `shared_ptr` syntax.