# C++: Call constructor of object inside of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I can't seem to find an answer to my question. Everything I've read on the matter seems to not quite connect and I'm starting to think what I want is impossible.

I'm working on a very very very light database management system, it's a college project and in my group I'm tasked with the main functions. Here's my problem:

We will run the project as `project.exe commands1.txt commands2.txt commands3.txt` for example.
Now, I have to create a std::vector containing objects of the "File" class so they can be used later by my colleagues doing the parsing. This is the class code (not finished, still working on)

```cpp
class File {
    protected:
        std::string name;
        std::fstream file;

    public: 
        File() {}

        File( // TO ADD REGEX
            std::string name
        ) {
            if (name != "")
                this->name = name;
            if (name != "" && !this->file) 
                this->file.open(consts::path + name);

        }       

        ~File(
        ) {
            this->name = "";
            if (this->file)
                this->file.close();
        }

        std::string getName(
        ) {
            return this->name;
        }

        void setName(
            std::string name
        ) {
            if (name != "") // TO ADD REGEX
                this->name = name;
        }

        std::fstream* getFile(
        ) {
            return &(this->file);
        }

        bool getStatus(
        ) {
            if (this->file)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    };
```

Also my main:

```cpp
int main(
    int argc,
    char* argv[]
) {
    
    std::string current_exec_name = argv[0];
    std::vector<std::string> all_args;
    all_args.assign(argv, argv + argc);
    
    std::vector<Files::File> commands = new // ???
}
```

How do I create a vector with n objects of the class File, so that each one is ran with the constructor `File( std::string name )`, with name being the equivalent argument in argv[ ]?

Read everywhere that you can initialize them like ([C++ FAQ](https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/arrays-call-default-ctor.html))

```cpp
class Fred {
public:
  Fred(int i, int j);      ← assume there is no default constructor
  ...
};

int main()
{
  Fred a[10] = {
    Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7),  // The 10 Fred objects are
    Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7), Fred(5,7)   // initialized using Fred(5,7)
  };
  ...
}
```

but I can't use this style since I don't know how many commands (.txts) will be sent.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for a `for` loop. Do you know how to use loops?

Comment: I believe having a `std::fstream` member in your class will make it uncopyable which will cause issues putting it into a `vector` without some additional work.  [Non-copyable elements in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906014/non-copyable-elements-in-vector) Usually you wouldn't check `!this->file` before calling `open`. You're in the constructor, the stream has just been initialized. Likewise you wouldn't call `close` manually either, the stream destructor will handle that. I would expect a function like `std::fstream* getFile` to return a reference and not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the simplest approach is to just tell the compiler to construct your vector from a range. You could even use (almost) the same range you used to assign values to `all_args`. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class File {
  public:
    File(std::string name) {
        std::cout << "File: " << name << "\n"; // To confirm each construction
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<File> commands(argv + (argc > 0 ? 1 : 0), argv + argc);
}
```

This says that `commands` is to be constructed from a range. Each element (each `char*`) from `argv+1` to `argv+argc` is used to construct an element of `commands`. (The weird expression `(argc > 0 ? 1 : 0)` is to handle the case where no arguments were provided.) Since `char*` implicitly converts to `std::string`, the constructor taking a `std::string` is used.

I did tweak the range to exclude the first argument. I suspect you do not want to construct a `File` based on the name of your program (what you stored in `current_exec_name`), but you could always drop the "+ weird expression" if my suspicion is wrong.

---

Since you did some digging around, here's a bonus reference for you: [the vector constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector); I used #5.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you. In the meantime, I also found the question 255612 which solved this issue by overloading the = operator

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a loop, calling the vector's `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` method on each iteration, eg:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    std::string current_exec_name = argv[0];
    std::vector<std::string> all_args;
    all_args.assign(argv, argv + argc);
    
    std::vector<Files::File> commands;
    commands.reserve(all_args.size());

    for (auto &arg : all_args) {
        commands.push_back(Files::File(arg));
        // or:
        commands.emplace_back(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and this will be helpful too, but my problem was regarding this part in particular:  commands.push_back(Files::File(arg)); . It won't run because i did not overload the = operator for my class. Someone pointed out to me a possible solution in another question (255612), and it worked.